# Multiply parameter from query in Excel (ODBC)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

Using in Excel: Get Data>Other sources>Microsoft Query I had a table getting data from our company ERP system (ODBC).

I have a table in Excel and then I click in Excel: Data>Queries&Connections>Properies>Connection Properties>Definition and in "Command text" i put this simple SQL command:

```
SELECT F4111.ILLITM, F4111.ILTRQT/1000,  F4111.ILTRUM, F4111.ILDGL, F4111.ILGLPT, F4111.ILDCT, F4111.ILUNCS, F4111.ILPAID, F4111.ILDOC, F4111.ILMCU
FROM RBGDC0P2.UREEUPBD.F4111 F4111
WHERE (F4111.ILLITM IN ('XXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYY')) AND (F4111.ILDCT LIKE '%AA%')
```

`XXXXXXX` and `YYYYYYY` are my input codes, which I need some data for them. 'F4111' is a table, `ILLITM` is my column from ERP database.

I can put `?` to open a parameter and connect in to particular cell in Excel, and then I can simply change this cell in excel and refresh a table a have output for different input codes.

My question is: I want to have more parameters, like I put in excel column with 100 input codes and I need output for them by refreshing my table query. I can do it for one or few inputs by putting '?', but how can I do it for more?